# Android - The local variable tst may not have been initialized

Tags: android

My work code is

```
@Override
    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) 
    {
        Toast tst;

        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.menuVada) {
            tst = Toast.makeText(Main.this, " Vada ", 2000);

        } else {
            tst = Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Menu Title: " + item.getTitle()
                    + " Menu ID: " + item.getItemId(), 2000);
        }
        tst.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        tst.show();

        return true;

    }
```

but this code not work

```
@Override
    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) 
    {
        Toast tst;

        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.menuVada) {
            //tst = Toast.makeText(Main.this, " Vada ", 2000);

        } else {
            tst = Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Menu Title: " + item.getTitle()
                    + " Menu ID: " + item.getItemId(), 2000);
        }
        tst.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        tst.show();

        return true;

    }
```

why not work my code ?

Please help.

Best Regards

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What if `(item.getItemId() == R.id.menuVada)`?

simply initialize `tst` to `null`. And then check if `tst!=null` show the toast

```
@Override
    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) 
    {
        Toast tst = null;

        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.menuVada) {
            //tst = Toast.makeText(Main.this, " Vada ", 2000);

        } else {
            tst = Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Menu Title: " + item.getTitle()
                    + " Menu ID: " + item.getItemId(), 2000);
        }
        if(tst!=null){
            tst.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            tst.show();
        }

        return true;

    }
```

Comment: This could be cleaned up a bit by moving the declaration, .setGravity and .show into the else clause.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `Toast tst;` should be initialized in both
`if` and `else` conditions.

becasue if you find your `if()` condition `true` then the `else` part will never be called.
and application flow will proceed to next and
will cause `NullPointerException`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in the if branch, tst is not initialiyed. But if you are showing the Toast in only one branch, I'd put the declarataion, gravity and show lines in that branch too.

```
@Override
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) 
{

    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.menuVada) {

    } else {
        Toast tst = Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Menu Title: " + item.getTitle()
                + " Menu ID: " + item.getItemId(), 2000);
        tst.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        tst.show();
    }

    return true;

}
```

Otherwise take Serif's way.

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize a variable before using it. Try this:

```
Toast tst = null;
```

But you *will* get a null reference exception if the code *doesn't* take the `else` branch. So, in a way, you could still say that the code doesn't work... It just compiles.

Answer (score 0):

Because if your `if()` test is true, it'll go into the empty branch where the assignment of `tst` is commented out. `tst` is therefore uninitialized when you get to `tst.setGravity()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make it static Like

```
Static  tst;
```

Or make it to store tst in another variable then acces your class Toast like

```
Toast  t = new Toast();
t.tst = // your variable
```

Hope it will work

Answer (score -1):

You could simply try :

```
@Override
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) 
{
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.menuVada) {
        Toast.makeText(Main.this, " Vada ", 2000);

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Menu Title: " + item.getTitle()
                + " Menu ID: " + item.getItemId(), 2000);
    }
    return true;
}
```

**EDIT accordind to comment.**

Comment: I edited my post, thx for correcting me. My point was just that you do not need do have a Toast tst.