# Variable 'snackbar' might not have been initialized

Tags: java, android

I am getting this error message saying that `Variable "snackbar" might not have been initialized`.

The following is part of my **MainActivity.java** code:

```
public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    NetworkInfo info = intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);

    if (info != null && info.isConnected()) {
        final Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "WiFi change detected; updating information...", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
            .setAction("DISMISS", new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    snackbar.dismiss();
                }
            });
            snackbar.setActionTextColor(Color.BLUE);
            snackbar.show();

            getWifi();
    }
}
}
```

I had read the accepted Stack Overflow answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7472408/android-the-local-variable-tst-may-not-have-been-initialized) and it suggests that I initialize `snackbar` immediately after `public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver`. So, I changed the code to:

```
/* no changes here */
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Snackbar snackbar = null;

    /* no changes here */
    if (...) {
        snackbar = Snackbar.make(...);
    }

    /* no changes here */
}
```

But this gives me an error `Variable "snackbar" is accessed from within inner class, needs to be declared final` and a warning `Method invocation "snackbar.dismiss()" may produce "java.lang.NullPointerException"`.

Any suggestions on how to solve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Split up your chained method calls:

```
final Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "WiFi change detected; updating information...", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
snackbar.setAction("DISMISS", new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      snackbar.dismiss();
    }
  });
```

This way, `snackbar` is definitely assigned before you create the `OnClickListener`.

Comment: Just curious, is this a bug in Android studio or am I meant to code it the way you've suggested?

Comment: This is not a bug. It is because of the way that anonymous classes are implemented, which is actually quite clear once you poke around a bit. I was actually writing up a detailed explanation... will continue and post a link here.

Comment: Thanks @Andy Turner, looking forward to reading your article :)

Comment: @YikJin http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35204884/variable-example-might-not-have-been-initialized-in-anonymous-class/35204885#35204885

Comment: Thanks @Andy Turner! That was helpful! Hope people who had this question find your answer useful too.

Answer (score -5):

As a workaround to

> `Variable "snackbar" is accessed from within inner class, needs to be declared final`

you can make that variable a final one-element array

Comment: Yes it is, but if you REALLY know what you are doing, it can work. But, yeah, you shouldn't do that.

Comment: Even if you REALLY know what you're doing, it is still terrible code.

Comment: If you think this is a good solution then you certainly DON'T know what you are doing...