# "Variable example might not have been initialized" in anonymous class

Tags: java, anonymous-class

*This [self-answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) was inspired by [Variable 'snackbar' might not have been initialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35200756/variable-snackbar-might-not-have-been-initialized/35200841?noredirect=1#comment58124611_35200841). I felt that there was more detail which would be better added separate from that specific question.*

Why can the following code not be compiled?

```
public class Example {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Runnable example = new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        System.out.println(example);  // Error on this line
      }
    };
  }
}
```

Compilation error:

```
error: variable example might not have been initialized
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This occurs because of the way that anonymous classes are implemented. You can see this if you make a slight change to the code and then decompile:

```
    final Runnable other = null;
    final Runnable example = new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        System.out.println(other);
      }
    };
```

i.e. make the anonymous class refer to a different local variable. This now will compile; we can decompile using `javap` and see the interface of the anonymous class:

```
final class Example$1 implements java.lang.Runnable {
  final java.lang.Runnable val$other;
  Example$1(java.lang.Runnable);
  public void run();
}
```

(`Example$1` is the name by which Java internally refers to the anonymous class).

This shows that the compiler has added a constructor to the anonymous class which takes a `Runnable` parameter; it also has a field called `val$other`. This name of this field should hint that this field is related to the `other` local variable.

You can dig into the bytecode further, and see that this parameter is assigned to `val$other`:

```
  Example$1(java.lang.Runnable);
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       // This gets the parameter...
       1: aload_1  
       // ...and this assigns it to the field val$other
       2: putfield      #1                  // Field val$other:Ljava/lang/Runnable;
       5: aload_0
       6: invokespecial #2                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       9: return
```

So, what this shows is the way that anonymous classes access the variables from their enclosing scope: they are simply passed the value at construction time.

This should hopefully show why the compiler stops you from writing code such as that in the question: it needs to be able to pass the reference to the `Runnable` to the anonymous class in order to construct it. However, the way that Java evaluates the following code:

```
final Runnable example = new Runnable() { ... }
```

is to fully evaluate the right-hand side first, and then assign it to the variable on the left-hand side. However, it needs the value of the variable on the right-hand side in order to pass into the generated constructor of `Runnable$1`:

```
final Runnable example = new Example$1(example);
```

That `example` hasn't been previously declared is not a problem, since this code is semantically identical to:

```
final Runnable example;
example = new Example$1(example);
```

so the error that you get isn't that the variable cannot be resolved - however, `example` hasn't been assigned a value before it is used as an argument to the constructor, hence the compiler error.

---

It might be argued that this is simply an implementation detail: it shouldn't matter that the argument has to be passed into the constructor, as there is no way that the `run()` method can be invoked prior to the assignment.

Actually, that's not true: you can invoke `run()` before the assignment, as follows:

```
final Runnable example = new Runnable() {
  Runnable runAndReturn() {
    run();
    return this;
  }

  @Override public void run() {
    System.out.println(example);
  }
}.runAndReturn();
```

If referring to `example` inside the anonymous class were allowed, you would be able to write this. Hence, referring to that variable is disallowed.

Comment: Really nice! Having the decompiled `Example$1` class pretty much shows _why_ should `other` be `final`. If it wasn't, the `Example$1` could potentially be dealing with an out-of-date copy of `other`, which would be ... strange, to say the least.

Answer (score 6):

You can use "this" to avoid the compilation error:

```
final Runnable example = new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    System.out.println(this);  // Use "this" on this line
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

To add something to David response

If you have multiple anonymous classes layers and you need to do that.

Store "this" in a field

```
      new AnonClass1(){
         private AnonClass1 internalRef=this;
    
         public void methodClass1(){
              new AnonClass2(){
                  public void methodClass2(){
                     doSomethingWithClass1(internalRef);
                  }
              }
         }
      }
```

Comment: If you get to the point of nesting anonymous classes and needing to refer to the outer instances, I think it might be worth stopping using anonymous classes. (In any case, you probably also want to make it `final`).